# How feasible is it to extend Microsoft's JDBC driver?

Tags: java, sql-server, encryption, jdbc, overriding

I'm currently working on a project where we have a Java web app bought from a 3rd party vendor that's connecting to SQL Server using Microsoft's JDBC driver. However, I've been given the requirement of having to encrypt the connection string using a proprietary encryption protocol.

So my question is how feasible would it be to extend the JDBC drivers distributed from Microsoft to incorporate this encryption. At this point I'm mainly thinking of creating a JDBC wrapper that will underneath use the Microsoft JDBC driver.

I'm open to other suggestions from more experienced people who might have done something similar in the past, or even if they could share pitfalls with this approach.

Comment: are you passing the connection string ot the driver yourself, or is some config framework handling that?  if the former, then just decrypt it yourself and pass it along.

Comment: You can use an open source [`jTDS` driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/index.html) as your starting point. The driver is compatible, and it worked fine the last time I checked (which was seven years ago).

Comment: @jtahlborn: the web app's configuration framework is handling that and just simply passing the connection string to the driver. The web app vendor suggested we do the decryption at the JDBC driver level, to accomplish this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use SSL which is baked into the SQL product?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898

Comment: @Ben Thul, it's a matter of requirements, I HAVE to use a specific type of encryption on the connection string. It's not a matter of security per se.

Comment: @EstebanBrenes: That's an odd requirement. You know your system best, but I'd question why that requirement is there. Specifically, you could use a standard that's been tested by a lot of people or you could blaze your own trail and hope you get it right. I know which I'd choose.

Comment: @BenThul It's really not up to me to decide, and yes I agree it's a bit of an odd requirement. However, it is better than the vendor-provided security used to encrypt the connection string which is PBEWithMD5AndDES or BASE64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jtds.  It's all java, works great for sql server, and supports encryption.  It's a drop in replacement minus setting up encryption.  You just need to know where they've configured their JDBC URL (hopefully in a configuration file under WEB-INF or some place like that), put in your jtds URL in there, and drop the Jar in the WEB-INF/lib directory.  You may have to extract the WAR file and repackage it with jtds.  It just depends on how this 3rd party vendor has deliver their app to you.  And yes I've shipped production packaged enterprise software using it for years.

http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

So say they have a simple properties file like this:

```
db.url=jdbc:mssql:....
db.username=bibby
db.password=blahblahblah
```

Change it to:

```
db.url=jdbc:jtds:<server_type>://<server>[:<port>][/<database>][;<property>=<value>[;...]]
db.username=bibby
db.password=blahblahblah
```

Of course you'll have to fill in all of the <> and [] parts as needed.  Then copy jtds.jar and any dependencies it needs into WEB-INF/lib and restart the server.  It should work.

Answer (score 1):

if the original driver does not have your desired function -> you could fetch the official release (or fork it) and patch/add your needs

https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/releases

Answer (score -1):

> At this point I'm mainly thinking of creating a JDBC wrapper that will underneath use the Microsoft JDBC driver.
>   I guess that you need a proxy on server side to decrypt the connection inforamtion, and forward database connection to SQLServer's port.